# 404 Not Found on apt update

Tags: apt

I've been having some issues with my Ubuntu since updating to 18.04.

Console gives me these errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/universe/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
```

After i started having issues, i tried copying my sources.list file a file i found, on someones github. https://gist.github.com/jackw1111/d31140946901fab417131ff4d9ae92e3

I've tried to disable the firewall, and google has only led me to posts from old versions refering to mismatched ppa(?) links.

This is my sources.list as it is right now:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team. deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

I have 2 other files in the sources.list.d, `microsoft-prod.list`  `resilio-sync.list` - could these be an issue? They dont seem to be the ones causing an issue.

I do live in Denmark, and have tried to replace the "us" with both "da" and "dk" to no use.

Comment: The main repos don't have armhf packages. You need http://ports.ubuntu.com/ for that.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what they even do. Are they needed? The machine is a regular old desktop used as a "server".

Comment: Only you can tell whether you need ARM packages. Did you do `dpkg --add-architecture armhf`? Otherwise those shouldn't be showing up.

Comment: I don't even find the links in my list file. If i don't have any ARM cpu's in the system, I'd assume I wornt need any packages.

Comment: No, I don't remember running that command. I did just try, and still the same

Comment: Running the command, and --remove-architecture did work tho.

Comment: since you have solved this, could you please post an answer describing what you did?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it seems I may previously have run the command `dpkg --add-architecture armhf` hence it was breaking it, thanks to muru for the assistance.

The computer I'm using only has a CPU with AMD64 architecture, hence the ARM would obviously not work.

Running the command "reversed" as in: `dpkg --remove-architecture armhf` fixed the issues, and I've now successfully updated.